# nodeJS chat app created. How to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, chat, multi-user

I have created nodeJS io.socket chat app using the link here -
http://cestfait.ch/content/chat-webapp-nodejs

I am able to run it on my laptop. I did not find any help on google how to connect to nodeJS app from other machines. I have another laptop which I have connected through wifi.

Now I really want to know how can I connect another user from another laptop to the nodeJS server running on my first laptop.

I will be very grateful for your help. Any help in broader sense will also be ok.

**EDIT 1:**
When I am trying Brandon's method, I am getting following error. Not sure what is wrong. I have to run the file `client.html` directly in the browser. Running `http://192.168.43.244:8000/client.html` throws the error.

```
C:\node>node server.js
   info  - socket.io started

C:\node\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /*!
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: In client.html, http://localhost:8000, change localhost to the local IP address of the PC running the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated.

If you don't have a static IP address (and you probably don't) that means every time you reconnect your computer to the internet, you are going to get a new IP address, so you'd have to update your code every time.

Also, there are issues with Firewalls, both on your dev machine and with (wifi) routers.

Best solution is to acquire a static IP. But its not cheap

Comment: Static IPs are about 5 bucks/month from most ISPs. You can also run your own cloud server for slightly more. Not sure what your definition of cheap is, but that seems reasonable.

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Most ISPs in the U.S. require you to buy moderately expensive "business-grade" service as a prerequisite to paying for a static IP.  The static IP itself is not too expensive, but the necessary business-grade service usually has higher cost-per-bandwidth (presumably with an increase in customer service or connection uptime).

Comment: Oops, previous comment should have been directed to @Jordan.

Comment: Or use dynamic DNS to map the server to a "domain name". Then use the link with a port number specified.

Comment: CenturyLink offers static IPs for $6 dollars, a month, (but i think there's a $25 activation fee)

Comment: Seriously guys, we're talking $100/year to just get your own server. I don't know how much cheaper you want. Or use Dynamic DNS, or pay some money to get the static through your ISP. It really isn't that much money.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure Socket.IO is connecting to the server serving the HTML. In `client.html`, change:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Leaving out the host/port will cause Socket.IO to connect to the same host and port serving the HTML.

Once you've done that, you can access the server from another computer by visiting `http://1.2.3.4:8000`, where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of the computer running the server. The connecting computer and the serving computer will need to be on the same network for this to work; if you want to (temporarily) connect with someone on a different network, you can use a tool like [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).

Comment: Or any dynamic DNS service, if you don't mind it being semi-public.

Comment: I have tried your answer and the problem I am facing is added to the answer. Please refer to that. Can you help me with that? Many thanks.